# Push notification handler on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

Following this example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx) I have enabled my Windows Phone 8 app for push notifications. I can receive notifications and the callback method `PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived` is called. From the example, this method opens a message box with the notification contents.

Can I therefore assume that it is safe to execute UI related operations from the thread the callback is executed in? I see that the message box is wrapped in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>`, however I have no idea what thread this will be executed in, and what objects I should use from this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived` is always called by the OS when a push notification is received while your app is running so it will execute on a non-UI thread.

Any UI related code that needs to be executed must be wrapped inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action a)` otherwise you'll get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. So `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action a)` magically executes the code in the UI thread and thats it, problem solved? :)